# AngularJS + SwipeJS not working without setTimeout of 0 milliseconds

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, settimeout, swipe

I am writing an AngularJS directive that makes it easy for me to create swipeable pages (such as the viewpager on Android). I use [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com/) as library for this.

This is how I use the directive

```
<ng-swipe ng-if="model.messages">
    <div class="page" ng-repeat="message in model.messages">
        {{message.title}}
    </div>
</ng-swipe>
```

And the code of the directive looks like this.

```
var swipe = angular.module('ngSwipe', []);

swipe.directive('ngSwipe', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template:
                '<div>' +
                '    <div id="slider" class="swipe">' +
                '        <div class="swipe-wrap" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '    </div>' +
                '    <div class="pagecontrol">' +
                '        <div class="pagedot" ng-repeat="p in swipe.pages" ng-click="swipe.switchPage($index)"></div>' +
                '    </div>' +
                '</div>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var $model = $scope.swipe = {
                pages: [],
                switchPage: function(index) {
                    $model.swipe.slide(index);
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                $model.swipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
                    continuous: false,
                    callback: function(index, elem) {
                        $model.currentTab = index;
                    }
                });

                for(var i=0; i<$model.swipe.getNumSlides(); i++) {
                    $model.pages.push(i);
                }

                $scope.$apply();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

First of all, the reason I use ng-if in the ng-swipe directive is because the link method should be invoked after my messages are loaded. The messages are being retrieved from the server and it can take up to 2 seconds before they are retrieved. If I don't wait untill the messages are loaded, the new Swipe() object will be created but it won't find pages so it will not work.

But besides that, you can also see that I have a setTimeout() function of 0 milliseconds. If I don't use that one, it just doesn't render the swipe pages.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamV/CwQad/1/) for this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
switchPage: function(index) {
  $model.swipe.slide(index);
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Comment: The issue is not that the paging does not work, the issue is that the pages are not being rendered when I remove the setTimeout() wrapper function. You can alter the JSFiddle to test it.